# Target DIRECTLY next element by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to target DIRECTLY the next `<section>` after the element `<section class="active">`

Here is code.

```
    <main>
        <section id="video" class="active">
            <video src="1.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
        </section>
        <section id="video">
            <video src="2.mp4" muted autoplay loop></video>
        </section>
        <section id="video">
            <video src="3.mp4" muted autoplay loop></video>
        </section>
    </main>
```

I've tried this one

```
`$(this).next().find($("video").prop('muted', false));`
```

and this one

```
`$(this).closest().find($("video").prop('muted', false));`
```

but both of them takes all `<section>`s and makes their videos unmuted.

I just want to unmute directly the next section's video which has class .active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're chaining your calls slightly wrong.  Try:

```
 $(this).next().find('video').prop('muted', false);
```

To explain:

.next() -> (Returns the immediate sibling element) -> find('video') (Returns the 'video' element contained in this sibling) and finally -> .prop() (set the property value)

'Find' takes a selector as an argument, rather than a jquery object.

Also, it's bad to have multiple elements with the same 'ID' on a page.  If you need to apply common styles, consider using classes instead.